# Notes field on Outlook contacts is incredibly small

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

One of my users came to me today with an interesting problem: The notes field in all of his contacts is appearing extremely small and is **unreadable at 1024X768** (pictured below). For the record this is a sales person with **100's of contacts** so manually changing them is out of the question.

The settings are `Calibri` and `11 point` font however they appear like 2-3 point font. I can easily change the font by right clicking within the body of the notes section however I can not seem to find the global setting.

Thus far I have tried:

- All the options under `tools>options>mail format>stationary and fonts`.
- The font setting under `tools>options>preferences>note options`.
- The font settings when in the contacts pain under `view>current view>customize current view>other settings`.

I'm not sure where else to look.

A [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=outlook%202007%20contacts%20notes%20field%20font&hl=en&prmd=ivnsfd&ei=wbfBTfLfFcPr0QHBmdC3Cg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1262&bih=891) search leads me to believe this a problem others have however no one seems to be able to solve it.

Even if you don't have an answer any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated, I don't want to just tell this user he's screwed...

**Outlook 2007** and the OS is **Windows XP Pro**.

Screen shot:

[image: Screen shot with the small text]

Comment: I told the user he's screwed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if the user has `Calibri` font installed?

Comment: Yes he has the Calibri font installed and it displays it fine in messages and in notepad.

Comment: is it possible that a New Style Set has been created and applied by default? What do Style Inspector and Reveal Formatting show? Something is being applied to reduce the size

Comment: It was the style set! sry you didn't @me so I didn't even see this post... accepted and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem, but found a fix!  Somehow, the ZOOM was set to 10%.  Here's the fix:  Go through the steps of sending an email message...you'll see that your typing is now incredibly small.  So the problem isn't just with CONTACTS, it with the Outbox too.  Type an outgoing email and then go to ZOOM and set it to 100%.  That solved my CONTACT problem and the Outbox problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open any contact, the click the Format Text tab on top of the screen, click on Change Styles and voila Bob's your uncle. Then go to the zoom button and choose your size.